# Setting ACLs correctly for -rw-r--r--+

Tags: permissions, acl

I've been able to set the default ACL permissions for new files like so:

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm u:usernamehere:rwx /var/www/path/to/files
```

This seems to give all new files a permission of:

```
-rw-r-----+
```

I'm hoping to have new files get a permission of the following instead:

```
-rw-r--r--+
```

If it makes any difference, I'm running CentOS.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that files ACLs that have ACL entries for named users or groups also have an *ACL mask* entry that limits the permissions given by those ACL entries and that of the group owner entry. The mask entry shows as the group permissions to `ls` and other utilities that only look at the traditional permission bits.

So, if your `ls` shows `-rw-r--r--+`, the ACL mask is `r--`, which means that the permission ACL `u:usernamehere:rwx` will act as `u:usernamehere:r--`. That may not be what you want. On the other hand, note that `u:usernamehere:rwx` is different from `u::rwx`, even for files owned by `usernamehere`. The first is a named entry, limited by the mask, while the second is the entry for the file owner which is *not* limited.

The idea of the mask is that a tool that runs the equivalent of `chmod go-rwx` can still make the file inaccessible to anyone but the owner. You can remove the mask entry with `setfacl -x m:: filename`, but it only works if there are no named user or group entries.

In any case, you can add more than one default entry on the same command. This would set default entries so that the file owner gets permissions `rwx`, the mask is set to `r--`, and permissions for "others" are set to `r--`:

```
$ setfacl -R -d -m u::rwx -m m::r-- -m o::r-- /path
```

You may want to explicitly set a default ACL for the group owner too (`g::`), since the entry appears in any case (with the values probably taken from the permission bits). E.g. here, the entry for the group owner isn't fully in effect, since the mask restricts it:

```
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x              #effective:r--
default:mask::r--
default:other::r--
```

A file created in the directory shows in `ls` as `-rw-r--r--+`.

---

Then again, if you just want the named user to get the permissions you say, you can leave the mask field out, and `setfacl` will set it for you based on the permissions you used for the actual ACL entries:

```
setfacl -R -d -m u::rwx -m u:usernamehere:rwx -m o::r-- /path
```

A file created in the directory now shows in `ls` as `-rw-rw-r--+`, and in `getfacl`:

```
user::rw-
user:usernamehere:rwx           #effective:rw-
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

The mask is missing the `x` since I created the file with `touch`, and it uses the permissions `0666`, masking the `x` bits out.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately I couldn't get either command to adjust the file permissions, and I'm assuming that's something that I'm doing incorrectly. For what it's worth, the file permissions get adjusted perfectly if I just run "sudo find /var/www/path/to/files  -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;" 
Any ideas?

Comment: @BestDevTutorials, yes, well, but is it perfect that way? Changing the group permissions via `chmod` changes the ACL mask, and limits what the `u:usernamehere:rwx` set of permissions can allow. I don't know what permissions you actually want.